# Change ToolBar Title dynamically on click events in Fragment on Xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin.android

First let me explain something, so you guys can understand better my problem:

I'm using Toolbar and i  have a Fragment called Location Fragment where i have 6 floationg action button vertically .
When you click on one of the floating action button some action like geofence,live tracking,current location etc are performed on the same map fragment.

So my problem is that when i  click any of the floation action button ,like when i click geo-fencing floation action button    the title on the tool bar should change  with the geofence title..In this way for all the Floating action button the title of toolbar should change. in my case the title of the tool bar is not changing .

I have tried  to use setTitle or this.Activity.Title="Geo-fence" on the click method of Floating action button,but still it remains same title .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Change ToolBar Title dynamically on click events in Fragment

In your `Fragment`, add the following code in your click events :

```
((AppCompatActivity)Activity).SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.YourTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

this.SupportActionBar.Title = "Your Title";